# При выкладывании приложения "Your binary is not optimized for iphone 5"

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone, icon

Собственно, выдаёт ошибку, как на картинке. Это из-за того, что я неправильно назвал какую-либо из иконок неправильно? (В разделе "Launch Images Catalog" я указал "Use asset catalog", может быть, в этом ошибка?)

[image]

Comment: @Zatoichy из картинок у меня только кнопки на главной (4 шт), т.е. я рисую кнопки (каждую кнопку в отдельном файле под свой размер и получается 48 кнопок (4 кнопки на каждый размер)) - и потом все 4 файла перетаскиваю в один размер?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Создаёте Image Set и заполняете изображения по ячейкам для каждого множителя (x1, x2, x3). Если для iPad требуются более крупные изображения, то можете в инспекторе переключить отдельно для iPad.

Comment: @Zatoichy простите за назойливость, но как кнопка напр. фон кнопки карты (backmap.png) будет фоном кнопки при другом разрешении если я назову её по другому. (сейчас у меня все картинки хранятся вместе с остальными файлами).

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Как я понял, сейчас у вас есть, например: backmap.png, backmapx2.png, backmapx3.png. Создаёте Image Set, задаёте имя backmap, заплняете соответственно изображениями. В IB выбираете кнопку и выбираете из списка backmap или если через код то, например так:
[button setImage:@"backmap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
В итоге картинка для нужного разрешения будет выбрана в зависимости от множителя.

Comment: @Zatoichy Спасибо, примерно понял, только что такое "В IB выбираете"

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов "IB" = Interface Builder

Comment: @Zatoichy Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте launch image для iP5. Или вы её не туда положили.

Comment: @Zatoichy а добавлять иконки с каким именем и размером (в appicon они указаны, а в launch написано просто 2х или 1х)

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Если вы используете Assets Catalog, то откройте в левой панели (Project Navigator) Images.xcassets и укажите там все изображения которые вам нужны, имена там не имеют значения. При выборе "ячейки" для изображения, в инспекторе(правая панель) будет указан требуемый размер.

Comment: @Zatoichy Справа там указывается только expected size напр 640х1136, но не размер требуемой эконки

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Это размер изображения, который вы должны предоставить. Пиксель в пиксель.

Comment: @Zatoichy шириной 1136 пикселй??? о_О

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Это высота в портретной ориентации у 4 дюймового экрана iPhone 5. Ш х В.

Comment: @Zatoichy стойте, мне нужно указывать все изображения, используемые в приложении, или логотип такого размера нужно сделать?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Если вы решили использовать Assets Catalog то, по хорошему, нужно добавить все имеющиеся в приложении изображения. Все заставки, иконки для поддерживаемых устройств. Дополнительные изображения так же нужно поместить в каталог.